# Meteor can't connect to remote mongodb server

Tags: mongodb, meteor, passenger

I'm am using Phusion Passenger Standalone to deploy my application in our LAN.
If my application and mongodb are all in the same server then there's no problem. Here's How I did it

```
export MONGO_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor'
export MONGO_OPLOG_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/local'
export ROOT_URL='http://www.my-app.com'
```

Start Phusion Passenger

```
sudo -E passenger start --port 80 --user someusername --environment production --daemonize --sticky-sessions --app-type node --startup-file main.js
```

However when I wanted to separate them so I can have a dedicated Mongodb Server, my application cannot connect to it. Here's the  what I did

```
export MONGO_URL='mongodb://192.168.xxx.xx:27017/meteor'
export MONGO_OPLOG_URL='mongodb://192.168.xxx.xx:27017/local'
export ROOT_URL='http://www.my-app.com'
```

What am I missing here to be able to run my Meteor application using a remote server?

Comment: What's the **exact** error message? In a first step, can you a) login to remote mongo DB using a mongo shell (i.e. $ mongo 192.168.xxx.xx:27017/local) b) try to run a remote DB but don't use Passenger (set ROOT_URL to localhost:3000)

Comment: it does not have error.  during rendering, it will read what is in the database and once ready it will render the page... it keeps trying to connect to the database.. but this will not happen as stated if i have both my application and the database on the same server

Comment: I haven't done it yet,
but may be sounds like you are missing 
mongodb://oplog:123456@localhost:27017/local?authSource=meteor
so you are missing "?authSource=meteor"

Comment: So how did you setup the OPLOG exactly? I have a remote OPLOG setup running with 0.9.4, so this works. You can check http://blog.mongolab.com/2014/07/tutorial-scaling-meteor-with-mongodb-oplog-tailing and/or https://meteorhacks.com/how-to-scale-meteor.html to see whether you accidentally left sth out.

Comment: honestly I don't know if my application is using the oplog or not. i am still new to meteor and haven't really  on the oplog tailing. the environment set-up i showed above is based on the tutorial i followed... even if i take out the  [ export MONGO_OPLOG_URL='mongodb://192.168.xxx.xx:27017/local' ] command still it cannot connect to the remote server

Comment: Mmmh. That's strange. Which OS are you on? Did you try a) and b) of my first comment? Does this work? Which packages are you using (meteor list)?

Comment: more to the problem, i have a robomongo on my desktop and i tried connecting to the remote mongoddb server in our LAN and still cannot connect. However just this today i was able to connect to that server... =( so probably there's a problem in our network. i'll continue to do my investigation of what had happened.. Thanks for the inputs guys =)